# can not resolve SpringBootApplication in springboot 1.5.4.release

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I am learning spring boot now, so I download the demo generated by the auto generator in spring boot, but after I import this project into IDEA, something wrong happens, the IDEA can not resolve the SpringBootApplication annotation! So I can not even start the "hello world" with spring boot, can anyone encounter such problems?

Comment: Do you have the spring boot starter parent dependency?

Comment: yes, I did it , I just download the demo from spring.io , then I import it as a plain java project, so its dependencies can not be resolved by IDEA.

Answer (score 2):

I made a mistake while import spring.demo project, I should import it as a maven project so that its dependency can be resolved automatically, but what I have done is that I import it as creating a new project not a maven project , so its class can not be resolved automatically.